# Using a view of columns from pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

Is it possible to create a view of the values in a pandas column without making a copy? An example:

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd

class Aclass:
    pass

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,2),columns=['a','b'])
```

This works:

```
Aclass.a = df['a']
Aclass.a is df['a']
Out[51]: True
```

But not this:

```
Aclass.a = df['a'].values
Aclass.a is df['a'].values
Out[54]: False
```

I want to do this as a way to incrementally include pandas into a project without getting hit with too much extra memory usage.

Comment: In your first example you are taking a view of the series, but in the second you are calling the attribute `values` which returns a numpy array representation of the values so they are not the same, what's wrong with taking a view of the series?

Comment: There are numpy/scipy functions,  including some stuff in my code base,  that assumes an ndarray as input and hence doesn't accept the series view. I was hoping that I could implement pandas "under the hood".

Comment: I've experienced what you've mentioned, especially with sklearn, unfortunately this is sometimes a problem with those methods not calling the array attribute correctly, unfortunately in that case you may need to take a copy of the numpy array if you are worried about memory then you could then call `del df['a']` after taking a copy of the numpy values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in this case, you're not making a copy of the data, just the array "container".

There are lots of cases where `df.values` will return a copy (e.g. different data types for different columns or any case where the data isn't contiguous in memory), but for a simple series or a DataFrame with one datatype, it returns a view of the data.

Even if the array objects are different, they point to the same data buffer.  Only a few extra bytes of memory are used.

For example:

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,2),columns=['a','b'])

# Every time you call `values` a new array object is created:
print df.a.values is df.a.values # This will be False

# But the data is _not_ copied:
x = df['a'].values
y = df.a.values
print np.may_share_memory(x, y) #This will be True

# And if we modify "x" or "y", we'll modify the original data frame:
x[0] = -9
y[-1] = -8
print df

# However, this only holds for cases where the data can be 
# viewed as a numpy array.

# This will modify the original dataframe:
z = df.values
z[0,:] = -5
print df

# But this won't, because the types are different and "values" returns
# a copy:
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(int)
arr = df.values
arr[0,:] = 10
print df
```

Comment: Wow, great, thanks! This should be included in pandas FAQ. Unless it already is and I missed it...